# How to use AWS S3 for linux file system backup?

Tags: linux, backup, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

As many who have used AWS S3 realize, it isn't a file system, but everything in the bucket is an object. While using the aws cli to do backups of a Linux server to S3, it doesn't preserve the permissions and dates for the file. So if you needed to do a restore to the Linux server from the AWS S3 backup, it won't contain the Linux file system specific information about each file. Unlike doing an rsync to another Linux server for backup.

The other option is to create a compressed tar file on Linux, and upload that to AWS S3, but there is a file size limit. This also doesn't make it convenient to do incremental backups.

People keep talking about using AWS S3 for backups and how great that is, but I wouldn't want to be the Linux administrator who has to take a S3 bucket and restore it to a Linux system with it losing the file permissions and dates on Linux.

What is the solution which is also economical and simple to use?